# Java EE or Spring for PrimeFaces project - any difference?

Tags: spring, primefaces

I'm planning a project which will use Primefaces to generate its UI.

I understand that PrimeFaces as JSF library is somewhat more at home with Java EE than Spring, although there seems to be a lot of examples of using it together with Spring.

Are there any notable disadvantages of using Spring instead of Java EE for the DAO and service layer in a PrimeFaces project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It complicates the things, `Java EE` is complex enough for application developers(you need time to open dark parts and see the lights or i hope it:)) so my opinion if you don't have a requirement about it, don't use Spring and JSF together to better understand your bean lifecycle. You can find good dicussion in this [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249706/spring-mvc-vs-jsf). I prefer to use `HTML+Bootstrap` and `Spring MVC` or use `Seam Framework` for `JSF` or no framework just use pure `Java EE` support with `primafaces(JSF)` can be good.

Comment: The seam framework is dead as can be read on the [homepage](http://www.seamframework.org). It has been superseeded by [deltaspike](http://deltaspike.apace.org). That, withJEE, PrimeFaces, combined with [OmniFaces](http://www.omnifaces.org) and [picketlink](http://www.picketlink.org) instead of spring security or apache shiro, you have a powerful set of frameworks. But still this question is to much subject to opinion.

Comment: @KukeltjeThanks for information about Seam, i didn't know it. You are also right about question cover a lot of thing but main subject as i understand is it a good idea to use Spring with JSF(Primafaces in here) and to me it is not a good solution to clearly understand Java EE ecosystem. Because Spring and JSF has different lifecycle.

Comment: I have no (fairly recent) spring experience and am not a fan, but from reading I do think that you can combine the two in a decent way as long as you do not try to combine parts of spring and parts of JEE, but even that may not be true anymore

Comment: Good points! You seem to confirm what I had read in articles: Spring + JSF can be done, but is not ideal.

Comment: @user75Thanks, please share article link in here for further reading about this subject.

Comment: This is the most informative: http://www.beyondjava.net/blog/integrate-jsf-2-spring-3-nicely/
It's partly outdated, but there are updates at the bottom.